# Extract SQL string from table to execute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

How could I select a string from table and `insert into @t1` to get final result like :

```
|    Date1    |   Date2     |    Date3     |     Date4   |    Date5      | 
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|'Feb  5 2019'|'Feb  4 2019'|'Feb  1 2019 '|'Jan 30 2019'|'Jan 18 2019 ' |
```

I have to run a stored procedure to create a dynamic column.

After find the max number of columns, I create tables and try to insert into the table.

I want to select some statement from a string, and those SQL string stored in a table like this

My code shown:

```
declare @t1 table (id0 datetime,id1 datetime,id2 datetime,id3 datetime,id4 datetime)
INSERT INTO @t1 (id0,id1,id2,id3,id4)
select Dates = STUFF((    
         SELECT ',''' +TRSDate + ''''  FROM [StandaloneDWH].[zru].[r435_436tcr] where CLM_Id =90
            FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '')
```

After executing the code:

```
select Dates = STUFF((    
     SELECT ',''' +TRSDate + ''''  FROM [StandaloneDWH].[zru].[r435_436tcr] where CLM_Id =90
        FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '')
```

it shows:

```
|                                 Dates                                  | 
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|'Feb  5 2019','Feb  4 2019','Feb  1 2019 ','Jan 30 2019','Jan 18 2019 ' |
```

How could I execute like this and insert into @t1

```
select 
    'Feb  5 2019','Feb  4 2019','Feb  1 2019 ','Jan 30 2019','Jan 18 2019 '
```

to get final result?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
insert into @t1 (id0, id1, id2, id3, id4)
    select max(case when seqnum = 1 then trsdate end),
           max(case when seqnum = 2 then trsdate end),
           max(case when seqnum = 3 then trsdate end),
           max(case when seqnum = 4 then trsdate end),
           max(case when seqnum = 5 then trsdate end)   
    from (select r.*,
                 row_number() over (order by trsdate) as seqnum
          from [StandaloneDWH].[zru].[r435_436tcr] r
          where CLM_Id = 90
         ) r;
```

You could also use `pivot` for the logic.  Or generate dynamic SQL with your approach.

Comment: Yes, I was generating dynamic SQL, but conditional aggregation save my life!

Answer (score 0):

I'm gong to take a(n informed) guess that this is SQL Server.  So you could use sp_executesql to run this as dynamic SQL.  Big hint, this won't help you, because as soon as your query gets to the point where it executes the dynamic SQL you will leave the session, and the @t1 `TABLE` variable will be lost.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
SELECT @sql = 'DECLARE @t1 TABLE (id0 DATETIME, id1 DATETIME, id2 DATETIME, id3 DATETIME, id4 DATETIME);';
SELECT @sql += 'INSERT INTO @t1 (id0, id1, id2, id3, id4) SELECT ';
--SELECT @sql += STUFF((    
--         SELECT ',''' + TRSDate + '''' FROM [StandaloneDWH].[zru].[r435_436tcr] 
--       WHERE CLM_Id = 90
--            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');
SELECT @sql += '''Feb  5 2019'',''Feb  4 2019'',''Feb  1 2019'',''Jan 30 2019'',''Jan 18 2019'';';
SELECT @sql += 'SELECT * FROM @t1;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note I commented out your script and hardcoded the date values to show this working, but you will need to uncomment out your section, then delete the line below this.

Results:

```
id0 id1 id2 id3 id4
2019-02-05 00:00:00.000 2019-02-04 00:00:00.000 2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 2019-01-30 00:00:00.000 2019-01-18 00:00:00.000
```

Gordon's answer is what you really need, but I included this to show how you could salvage your existing script (you must have spent some time messing with `FOR XML PATH`?), and also why it won't work.